# Cannot Send Submit form data to another file process

Tags: php

Really need help....
I've got two scripts below:

index.php

```
<html> 
<head><title>Select Chain</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var htmlobjek; 
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
  //apabila terjadi event onchange terhadap object <select id=region> 
  $("#region").change(function()
  {
    var region = $("#region").val(); 
    $.ajax(
    { 
        url: "GetMSC.php", 
        data: "region="+region, 
        cache: false, 
        success: function(msg)
        {   //jika data sukses diambil dari server kita tampilkan 
            //di <select id=kota> 
            $("#msc").html(msg); 
        } 
    }); 
  }); 

  $("#sub_but").click(function()
  { 

        $.ajax(
        { 
            url: "ShowSCR.php", 
            type: GET,
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            cache: false, 
            success : function(data) 
            {
                $("#scr").html(data); 
            }
        }); 
  }); 
}); 
33   
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<?php 
include "conn.php";
include "q_table.php";
?> 

<form name="scr_form" id="scr_form">
<table border="2">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <font size="-1">Date From<br> </font>
           <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="datefrom"> 
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="if(self.gfPop)gfPop.fPopCalendar(document.scr_form.datefrom);return false;">
           <img name="popcal" align="absmiddle" style="border:none" src="./calender/calender.jpeg" width="34" height="29" border="0" alt="">
           </a>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <font size="-1">Date To<br> </font>
           <input type="text" name="dateto" id="dateto"> 
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="if(self.gfPop)gfPop.fPopCalendar(document.scr_form.dateto);return false;">
           <img name="popcal" align="absmiddle" style="border:none" src="./calender/calender.jpeg" width="34" height="29" border="0" alt="">
           </a>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
        <font size="-1">Region <br></font>
        <select name="region" id="region"> 
        <option value="0" selected="selected">--Pilih Region--</option> 
        <option value="AllReg"> <b>All Region</b> </option>
        <?php 
            while($p=mssql_fetch_array($q_region)){ 
            echo "<option value=\"$p[0]\">$p[1]</option>\n"; 
            } 
        ?> 
        </select> 
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>
        <font size="-1">MSC <br></font>
        <select name="msc" id="msc"> 
            <option selected="selected">--Pilih MSC--</option> 
        </select> 
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>  
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Process" name="proses" id="sub_but">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
<br>

<div id="scr">
</div>


</body> 
</html> 

<!--  PopCalendar(tag name and id must match) Tags should not be enclosed in tags other than the html body tag. -->
<iframe width=174 height=189 name="gToday:normal:./calender/agenda.js" id="gToday:normal:./calender/agenda.js" src="./calender/ipopeng.htm" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="visibility:visible; z-index:999; position:absolute; top:-500px; left:-500px;">
</iframe>
```

ShowSCR.php

```
<?php 



include "conn.php";


$datefrom = $_GET['datefrom']; 
$dateto = $_GET['dateto'];
$region = $_GET['region'];
$msc = $_GET['msc'];


if($msc == 'AllMsc')
{
    $q_msc2 = mssql_query("SELECT distinct DATE_ID, HOUR_ID, MSC, (SUM(Success_16/Attempt_16)*100) as SCR_16
  FROM SCR
  WHERE DATE_ID >= '$datefrom'
  and DATE_ID <= '$dateto'
  group by DATE_ID, HOUR_ID, MSC,Success_16,Attempt_16");
}elseif($msc != 0 or $msc != 'AllMsc')
{
    $q_msc2 = mssql_query("SELECT distinct DATE_ID, HOUR_ID, MSC, (SUM(Success_16/Attempt_16)*100) as SCR_16 
    FROM SCR 
    WHERE msc_id='$msc' 
    AND DATE_ID >= '$datefrom'
    AND DATE_ID <= '$dateto'
    group by DATE_ID, HOUR_ID, MSC,Success_16,Attempt_16"); 
}

    echo "$datefrom";
    echo "$dateto";
    echo "$region";
    echo "$msc";
    echo "

            <table border='2' width='50%'>
                <tr align='center'>
                    <td><b>Date</b></td>
                    <td><b>Time</b></td>
                    <td><b>MSC</b></td>
                    <td><b>SCR 16bit(%)</b></td>
                </tr>";


while($k = mssql_fetch_array($q_msc2))
{ 


$date_1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($k[DATE_ID]));
    echo "
                <tr>
                    <td align='center'><font size='-1'>$date_1</font></td>
                    <td align='center'><font size='-1'>$k[HOUR_ID]</font></td>
                    <td align='center'><font size='-1'>$k[MSC]</font></td>
                    <td align='center'><font size='-1'>$k[SCR_16]</font></td>
                </tr>



        ";
} 

    echo "</table>";

?>
```

The submit data form from index.php cannot send to ShowSCR.php.
I have already tried to change the function name depending on the button or form if, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: What you are doing is not secure, and is wide open to SQL injection.  You **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$(this).serialize()` through AJAX, but pay attention to what `this` represents. Here, it's the button you clicked. You need to get the form that the button belongs to, and serialize *that* instead.

Comment: sorry,,i didn't get your answer,,, i'm new to ajax and JS,,,

Comment: In JavaScript, `this` is in the context of the object the function is called from. In this case it is the button rather than the form.